# Compiler error with list<string>

Tags: c++, string, list, stl, managed-c++

I'm trying to create a list of strings, following the example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/list/). This below gives me syntax errors:

```
private: list<string> images;
```

The errors (all on the line where the above declaration is):

```
syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

It's in a class with only a single constructor besides it, and it compiles fine without it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably don't want a `list`, but a `vector`.

Comment: Posting the code could help to trace the error.

Answer (score 4):

Did you `#include` both `<list>` and `<string>`?  Also, did you import the names `list` and `string` from `namespace std` by writing either

```
using namespace std;
```

or

```
using std::list;   using std::string;
```

The error you're getting is consistent with the names not being accessible, so this is my best guess.

**EDIT**: Since this is in a header file, you should not be using either of the above constructs (thanks to wilhelmtell for pointing out that this is a header file!).  Instead, you should fully-qualify the names as

```
private: std::list<std::string> images;
```

This way the compiler knows exactly where to look for `list` and `string`.

Comment: Don't bring namespace `std` into the header!

Comment: @wilhelmtell- D'oh!  Didn't realize that was a header.  Answer updated appropriately.

Comment: @wilhelmtell So why shouldn't a namespace be brought into a header?

Comment: @quasiserve- If you have a `using namespace` declaration in a header, then any file that includes that header will implicitly import all of the names from that namespace into its global namespace.  This can result in inadvertent name conflicts and is very hard to trace down, since the source of the problem is buried deep within a header.  For this name, it's generally considered a good idea to use fully-qualified names inside a header rather than having a `using namespace` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to qualify the `list` and `string` types with their [namespace](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/).

Either type `std::list<std::string>` or add `using namespace std;` after the `#include <string>` and `#include <list>` directives.

A simple working program:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main ( int, char ** )
{
    list<string> strings;
    strings.push_back("1st string");
}
```

Comment: I used the qualified names and this is the error I get now: `cannot define 'images' as a member of managed 'MyClass::MyForm': mixed types are not supported`

Comment: @Igor: Managed C++ is not the same as C++, you should tag your question accordingly.